# Java sound doesn't work on Windows, but it work on OS X

Tags: java, swing, audio, embedded-resource, javasound

I have problem with playing sounds. 
Everything is working on OS X but on Windows it doesn't.

Actually I found some code for playing sounds
and I fixed it like this

```
private static synchronized void playSound(final URL url) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
                Clip play = AudioSystem.getClip(); 
                play.open(audioInputStream);
                play.start();
                play.drain();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

And I use it like this

```
playSound(getClass().getResource("/Sound_getMoney.wav"));
```

Sound_getMoney.wav is in the resource path

I don't know why it doesn't work on windows :(

please help me

Comment: Try using two backslashes instead of `/` for the path.

Comment: you mean that use `\\Sound_getMoney.wav` instead `/Sound_getMoney.wav`

Comment: yes. That extra \ is used to escape the \.

Comment: it doesn't work both of that OS

Comment: Try removing all the slashes.

Comment: It's not.. doesn't work. I think it is not causing by path.

Comment: What error does it give you? Where is your `Sound_getMoney.wav`? It should be in the same directory as your java file.

Comment: I got just 'null'. Actually I made a folder named "resources" under the project  folder and I set up build path for that.

Comment: `Class.getResource` does not work that way, put it together with your source code files.

Comment: ?? I have some images and I can use it by that way.

Comment: `Class.getResource` is searching the class path, unless your `resources` directory is in the class path, Java won't find them